# WPF Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Throw Exception

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I am using Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem like following

```
public void TestMain()
    {
        try
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.BackGroundMethod()));
                }
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void BackGroundMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 100;
            var error = b / a;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

By this way, TestMain() can not catch exception.
Program will shut down...

How can i catch this error?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.BackGroundMethod));` executes asynchonously, so it will finished execute all code inside `TestMain` before `BackGroundMethod` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dispatcher.UnhandledException` event to catch the exception in the `TestMain()` method like this:

```
Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(args.Exception.Message);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ignore => Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(BackGroundMethod)));
```

Edit: Remember to set the `Handled` property to prevent the internal exception handler from being called:

```
Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => 
{
    MessageBox.Show(args.Exception.Message);
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Dispatcher to create a new thread, that thread has it's own stack, and so the exceptions wont bubble to the try...catch in `TestMain`, but instead they will originate in `BackgroundMethod` method. As you are throwing the exception in `BackgroundMethod` your try catch is useless, and so if you were to not throw the exception in `BackgroundMethod` your program wouldn't shut down.

```
private void BackGroundMethod()
{
    try
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 100;
        var error = b / a;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You suggested you wanted your program to stop crashing, thats how you do it. Having a try..catch with nothing but a throw in it is pointless and just slows your program down. What I was explaining is that the exception originates in that method, which is on a separate thread and so your error handling must be in `BackgroundMethod` not in `TestMain` as some have suggested.

It is up to you how you handle the errors that surface in `BackgroundMethod` but you must handle them there - it doesn't matter how much error handling you put in `TestMain`

Comment: I've edited my code to show a message box, as you've got in your `TestMain` method

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all exceptions in all threads within the application by handling [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the crash, add a `try`/`catch` around the operation which might throw:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
{
    try {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.BackGroundMethod()));
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex) {
        // handle the error somehow
    }
});
```

However, think about what you are doing here: you are pushing some action to the thread pool, and in turn it pushes the same action to the dispatcher thread. Why not do this yourself directly without the `QueueUserWorkItem` call?

Comment: Beacuse of that code is only a sample. The real background method is a DB communicate method in other class. I used thread pool to let Ui better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by catching the exception in the BeginInvoke function and saving it in a temporary variable. After the await you can then rethrow it on the correct thread.

```
           Exception thrown = null;

        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Action>(x =>
        {
            try
            {
                BackGroundMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //exceptions on this thread MUST be caught or the program will exit
                //we will save it, and then when we are back on the main thread we will rethrow it
                thrown = ex;
            }
        }));

        if (thrown != null)
            throw thrown; //<--- I'm rethrowing it right here on the correct thread
```